# How to get reviews collection on homepage in magento?

Tags: magento1.9.3

I want to show product reviews on homepage with star rating, author name and review description but don't want to show product detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get review collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
            ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call function in Block file,

```
public function getRatings(){
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
    ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)->setDateOrder()
    ->addRateVotes();
    return $reviews;
    }
```

In view file,

```
$getRating = $this->getRatings();
//getting average votes
$avgRating = 0;
$ratings = array();
if (count($getRating) > 0) {
foreach ($getRating->getItems() as $review) {
    foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $voting ) {
        $ratings[] = $voting->getPercent();
    }
}
$avgRating = array_sum($ratings)/count($ratings);
}

<?php if($avgRating): ?>
    <div class="rating-box">
        <div class="rating" style="width: <?php echo ceil($avgRating) ; ?>%;"></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hi rakesh, this is my feedback form : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0 how can i get from all pages and home page?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.    Create review-list.phtml, put anywhere. in my case, catalog/product/review-list.phtml

Paste the below code.

```
 <?php 
            $_items = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection(); 
            if( count( $_items ) ){ ?>
                <div class="reviews-list">
            <?php         foreach( $_items as $_review ){
                        $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_review['entity_pk_value']);

                            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_review['entity_pk_value']);

                        if ($summaryData['rating_summary']):?> 
                        <div>
                                <div class="testtt">
                                    <div class="ratings">
                                        <div class="rating-box">
                                            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $summaryData['rating_summary']; ?>%"></div>
                                                <div class="pr-name1"><?php echo $summaryData['reviews_count'];?></div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php endif; 
                                echo '<div class="product_name"><span>Product Name:</span> '.$_product->getName().'</div></br>';?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $_product->getThumbnailUrl();?>" alt="<?php $_product->getName() ?>"/>
                            <?php     echo '<div class="review_title"><span>Review Title:</span> '.$this->htmlEscape( $_review->getTitle() ).'</div></br>'; 
                                echo '<div class="review_detail"><span>Review:</span> '.$this->htmlEscape( $_review->getDetail() ).'</div></br>'; 
                                echo '<div class="review_author"><span>NickName:</span> '.$this->htmlEscape( $_review->getNickname() ).'</div></br>'; 
                                echo '<small class="date">'.$this->__('(Customers Reviews on %s)', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long').'</small>';?>
                            </div>
                        <?php     }?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Step 2 : call reviews-list.phtml in cms-homepage.

```
{{block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/reviews-list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: In this case how can i get in all pages including home page?